Azure web app is using wrong connection string after slot swap
I have an Azure web app that was running for a couple weeks.  I just created a "staging" slot and added a slot-specific connection string to it, which I also did for the prod slot.  I swapped them and now my production and staging slots are both writing to the staging db.
I checked the environment variables in Kudu and it is correct for both apps.  I've tried restarting the app service.  I'm at a loss what to check next.
Update: Here are the Configuration Settings.  I had to zoom out quite a bit to get the whole thing so its a little small.

Here are the environment variables.  I have the connection string added, and the name is correct:

These settings are identical in both slots, except for the Catalog in the connection string.  This one is prod, the staging db has -staging appended to it.
Also, the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is either "Production" or "Staging".  The only thing that's used for is to get some Key Vault secrets for Oath with an external API.
I hope this helps.

Please share more details about the issue

Try reaching out to the Azure Support directly by creating a ticket. They might be able to better help you by assaying your configuration directly with you.
As @Harshitha requested, we need more details to even be able to assist you.

What additional information do you need?  I'm happy to provide as much as I can.

How does your configuration look?What is the framework and version of your app?Do you have any environment variables set?

@Harshitha I posted the updates you requested.  I wasn't sure what else to look for, so tell me how this information will help diagnose the problem.  Are there certain settings you're looking for?

@USMC6072 This one is prod, the staging db has -staging appended to it. you mean to say catalog=adobesign-staging??

@VivekVaibhavShandilya that is correct.

@USMC6072 Cross check if connection string is not hardcoded. in the new production code(previously staging)

I did, and there was nothing.  The only connection string in the code is in the appsettings.config and it is disregarded when published to Azure.  Plus, it has the prod connection string and not the staging.

I should have mentioned, I run the code locally and it saves to the correct db, so this is limited to Azure.  I deleted the slot and I'm going to test more.

@USMC6072 - Any update on the issue?

No. I was finally able to open a ticket with Azure support.  They are looking into it.
